# Is "holiday" derived from "holy day"?

Tags: etymology

I'm just curious if the word "holiday" is derived from "holy day".

Comment: Voted to close as all four answers are general reference.

Comment: Huh, interesting.  I always thought it came from "[Holly](http://www.piglette.com/christmas/holly-plant.jpg) day"..  Pronunciation matches _much_ better, after all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes**, from the Old English. The *New Oxford American Dictionary* says “ORIGIN: Old English hāligdæg [holy day.]”

Answer (score 8):

That's right. According to *[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=holiday&allowed_in_frame=0)*:

> O.E. *haligdæg*, from *halig*
>   "**holy**" + *dæg* "**day**;" in 14c.
>   meaning both "**religious festival**"
>   and "**day of recreation**", but
>   pronunciation and sense diverged 16c.

Answer (score 7):

The answers are above, but Barnhart's *Dictionary of Etymology* offers a bit more:

> Old English had a concurrent open
>   compound *halig daeg,* found later in
>   Middle English *holy day,* which
>   became modern English *holiday,*
>   meaning both a religious festival and
>   a day of recreation. This eventually
>   replaced the earlier form *haliday,*
>   leaving two forms *holiday* and *holy
>   day.*

Answer (score 1):

> Holiday is a compound stemming from the words holy and day.  The word 'holiday' first surfaced in the 1500's replacing the earlier word 'haliday' which was recorded before 1200 in the Old English book Ancrene Riwle.  Earlier , about 950, the word was 'haligdaeg' and appeared in the Old English Lindisfarne Gospels.  It was a compound of halig (holy) plus daeg (day)

Source: [en.allexperts.com](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Etymology-Meaning-Words-1474/Word-meaning-2.htm)